# Thigh and waist rig not moving

Tags: rigging, armature, parent

[image]

I'm quite new to parenting and rigging. I have tried referencing youtube tutorials but i'm still stuck with the same problem. After applying "With Automatic Weights", every body parts are moving except the waist and thighs.

Comment: Please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/